# Forcing oembeds to top of post

Tags: posts, templates, oembed

What's the best way to force oembed (or shortcodes too) to the top of a post?

I'd like to feature youtube embeds before the actual article content, regardless of where the link was inserted.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can create custom post meta which contain youtube url
and then

```
$yt=get_post_meta($post->ID,'youtube_url',true);
if( '' != $yt)
echo $GLOBALS['wp_embed']->autoembed( $yt );
```

**Updated:**

If i'm getting correctly then your content contain youtube url any where in it and you want to show them at top regardless there position in content.

jut paste this code in `functions.php`

```
add_filter('the_content','ravs_youtube_atTop',1);
function ravs_youtube_atTop($content){
    /* get list of all youtubr urls */
    preg_match_all('#https?://(www\.)?youtube.com/watch.*#', $content, $matches);
    /*replace all youtube url by empty string*/
    $content = preg_replace('#https?://(www\.)?youtube.com/watch.*#','',$content);
    /* return actual content if not youtube url found */
    if( empty($matches[0]) )
        return $content;
    /*insert all youtube embed iframes at top of content*/
    foreach( $matches[0] as $match){
        $content = wp_oembed_get($match).$content;
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: No way to do this with OEmbed?

Comment: answer updated.check is this one work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Part of your question asked about shortcodes. That is relatively simple.

```
function move_shortcode_to_top($content) {
  if (!is_singular()) return;

  $regex = get_shortcode_regex();
  preg_match_all('/'.$regex.'/',$content,$matches);

  $move_these = array(
    'testsc'
  );

  if (!empty($matches[2])) {
    foreach ($matches[2] as $k => $v) {
      if (in_array($v,$move_these)) {
        $content = $matches[0][$k].str_replace($matches[0][$k],'',$content);
      }
    }
  } 

  return $content;
}
add_action('the_content','move_shortcode_to_top',1);
```

Just provide a list (`$move_these`) of the shortcodes you want to move.

For oembeds, you need something a little different:

```
function move_oembed_to_top($content) {
  $pattern = '|^\s*(https?://[^\s"]+)\s*$|im';
  preg_match_all($pattern,$content,$matches);
  if (!empty($matches[1])) {
    $content = preg_replace($pattern,'',$content);
    $content = implode("\n",$matches[1])."\n".$content;
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','move_oembed_to_top',1);
```

That will move as many embeds as it finds. Tested with YouTube embeds.

Note: [That regex is *exactly* the one used by the Core embed system](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php#L246).