# Enqueue script only if page has an oembed

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, oembed

I have a script that adds some styles to OEmbedded content. At the moment its running on every page. I was wondering if anyone knew how to only enqueue the script if the page has an OEmbed on it.

I have no code to show as google doesn't return anything on the topic

Comment: What kind of oembedded content is this? Do you have code for the oembedding we can see that might aid in generating the code to enqueue such a script/style? Do you have any ideas or starting points you think might be helpful for others researching an answer?

Comment: Fair enough on the edit sorry I was in a bad mood. I've developed this really negative feeling about using this site, but its really good and helpful and the people on it are quite cool, so i need to change that :)

Comment: I assumed WordPress used the `video` or `embed` shortcode when spitting out the content. You may be able to use a version of [this function](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106296/forcing-oembeds-to-top-of-post) to test if a oembed is being used.

Comment: Things to note for potential answers, oembeds dont use shortcodes ( though shortcodes can use oembeds, e.g. the oembed shortcode ), and there is a caching mechanism for oembeds in post content

Answer (score 2):

Well the first thing to consider is that the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook fires before the filters on the page/post content are run.

So I would add a function to the `wp` action hook and test the content for oembeds there.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'your_oembed_test_function' );
function your_oembed_test_function(){
    //earliest reliable hook to get $post variable
    global $post;

    //do your tests with $post content

    if( $oembed_exists_results ) wp_enqueue_script( $your_handle );

}
```

Because WP fires before `wp_enqueue_scripts` you will be able to choose which scripts/styles you want to show based on which oembeds you find in the content.

Comment: Ah ok so would you check the content for whether it contained an url with an oembed in it? E.g. The oembed url is http://www.site.com/events/open-evening so you could just do a string check for http://www.site.com/events, and if it contained that, then you'd enqueue the event oembed script / style...?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was getting at.  Any filters specific to oembed are not fired until just before the content is being displayed, so that is why I am suggesting doing the check earlier.